# How can I fire an event when I select the same option again?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get an event when I hit an option of my select box, even if the option is already selected. The cause is, that I want to add the values to my list, with the possibility to add them multiple times.

Right now I can add `dog`and then `cat` and then `dog`. So in my list I have

dog

cat

dog

But it is not possible to add `cat` immediately after `cat`, so my list would look like this:

cat

cat

cat

```js
$(function () {
  //Initialize Select2 Elements
  $(".select2").select2();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".select2").on("change", function () {
    var classname = $(".select2 option:selected").val();
  $(".result").append("<li>" + classname + "</li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>



<div class="result"></div>
```

EDIT:
I found a solution that worked for me:

```js
$(function () {
  //Initialize Select2 Elements
  $(".select2").select2();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".select2").on("change", function () {
    var classname = $(".select2 option:selected").val();
  $(".result").append("<li>" + classname + "</li>");
  var should_be_selected = 'empty';
     $(".select2 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    $('.select2').find('.' + should_be_selected).attr('selected', 'selected');
   
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option class="empty"></option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>




<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Add a button next to the `select` and append the selected value to the list when the button is clicked

Comment: you're using change for the select tag! not for option! therefore your function only trigger when you change the value! try selecting "cat" for the first time!

Comment: Good ideas! I also thought about deselect all options after select change

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event only fires when the selected option changes - as its name implies. There's no reliable workaround for this behaviour if you want it to fire when the same option is chosen.

An alternative is to place a `<button>` in the DOM and then only insert the new `li` when the button is clicked, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".select2").select2();

  $(".add").on("click", function() {
    var classname = $(".select2").val();
    $(".result").append("<li>" + classname + "</li>");
  });
});
```

```css
.remove {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
  </select>
  <button class="add">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but I need a solution without an extra button

Comment: Shouldn't you also include the `change` event? What if I make a selection with my keyboard and press enter to make a choice :)? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me, see my question

Answer (score 0):

Adding the select2:close event worked for me:

```
$('.select2').on('select2:select select2:close', function (e) {
// Do what you need here
});
```